# Performing Coverity CLI Scan

Tags: coverity

I want to integrate Code Sight in my visual Studio Code. Why does Code Sight with Coverity connect taking more time to scan as compared to Coverity CLI?

I tried executing both. The difference was large. Coverity CLI is executing and scanning much faster then Coverity Code Sight.